# never logout session from wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, session, authentication

I'm working on a community networking site where users session never expires (unless log out button is pressed). Along with that I've wordpress cms integrated for blogging hosted in sub domain.. I use js to trigger login and logout on wordpress site.. Means when users login to main (non- wordpress) site, they are also automatically logged in to wordpress site.. Here now the problem is, after certain period of time or when browser is closed, the wordpress site automatically logged out from the system-leaving only main website in session, and that will need users to logged out from main website and again re-login just to trigger back the wordpress login...

I'd just want wordpress to never automatically (even if the windows is closed) logout unless logout button is pressed.. I used the following function which doesn't seems to work..

```html
function change_wp_cookie_logout( $expirein )
 { return 1555200; // 6 months in seconds
 } 
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'change_wp_cookie_logout' );
```

I've tried with different similar tactics but doesn't get it working..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to check about cookies, in my humble opinion that would be the best approach to persists the user data for a long term. You could use the cookies to restore their data in a new session using some key information. Basically, whenever they close the browser the **session** will expire (disconnected by the server), but if you have cookies on their end, you could check in server side when a new session is requrested if does it exist a cookie and based on the info you had store there, you can restore the info necessary on their web session.

You can read more about on oficial page:

https://en.support.wordpress.com/cookies/